# Make choropleth type plot from shapefile and its data

Tags: r, plot, shapefile

I have a shapefile showing neighborhoods within Baltimore, and the shapefile contains the names of the neighborhoods and mortality values for each 'hood.  The data is already there!  I just want to plot it so I get a color-coded plot of 10 (or any arbitrary number) of quantiles of the mortality values.

I've done a lot of searching on choropleths but haven't found anything that helps.

I hope I can provide enough info so people can help:

```
# load a bunch of packages just to be safe
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(lattice)

# I start using OGR tool
ogrListLayers("mortality.shp")
[1] "mortality"
mort <- readOGR("mortality.shp", "mortality")
summary(mort)
> summary(mort)
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
             min            max
x 1393926.784012 1445503.226141
y  557733.624942  621406.812556
Is projected: TRUE 
proj4string :
[+proj=lcc +lat_1=38.3 +lat_2=39.45 +lat_0=37.66666666666666 +lon_0=-77
+x_0=399999.9999999999 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs
+ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0]
Data attributes:
                                CSA        Mort_11            
 Allendale/Irvington/S. Hilton    : 1   Min.   :0.0083400000  
 Beechfield/Ten Hills/West Hills  : 1   1st Qu.:0.0346990000  
 Belair-Edison                    : 1   Median :0.0398540000  
 Brooklyn/Curtis Bay/Hawkins Point: 1   Mean   :0.0390734909  
 Canton                           : 1   3rd Qu.:0.0433880000  
 Cedonia/Frankford                : 1   Max.   :0.0696700000  
 (Other)                          :49                         

# I can easily get at the values I want to plot...but how to plot?
mort$Mort_11     # shows the mortality values

attributes(mort)   #produces a ton of output.  Here's a little:
$data
                                     CSA  Mort_11
0          Allendale/Irvington/S. Hilton 0.039854
1        Beechfield/Ten Hills/West Hills 0.040512
2                          Belair-Edison 0.050204
3      Brooklyn/Curtis Bay/Hawkins Point 0.049058
...
27             Inner Harbor/Federal Hill 0.034886
...
```

I figure it's got to be easy to just tell **R** to use the shape file and to use the data that's already in it. Is there an easy way to do this?  I figure it should just be a couple of lines since the shapefile contains all the relevant info.

Comment: link to the shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good tutorials on the web describing choropleth maps in ggplot2. 
First, Hadley Wickham's own: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles
Second, Spatial.ly:http://spatial.ly/2013/12/introduction-spatial-data-ggplot2/

Essentially, for ggplot2 one needs to use the fortify function to convert the spatial data to a standard dataframe, which can then be plotted as a polygons, setting fill to the variable of your choice.

Something like

```
p <- ggplot(data = mort, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = Mort_11)) + 
  geom_poly() + # plot the filled polygons
  geom_path(colour = "white") # add nice white borders to the polygons
p # render the plot
```